# How to have self-executing function in an object's prototype be auto-run for all children in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Every 'child' of a parent object needs to be subscribed to a fixed event in the event aggregator: For example:

```
var dispatcher = EventAggregator.create();
```

There are multiple 'views' in the application and all views must be subscribed to the close event. Using Backbone:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){
  //close logic
};
```

Now every view needs to subscribe to the "close" event on the event aggregator i.e. `var dispatcher` without needing to explicitly call a method to do it. That is instead of constantly saying:

`dispatcher.on('close', this.close)` or `ParentView.prototype.someMethod.apply()`

in every view that is an instance of Backbone.View is there a way to have all views automatically be subscribed to the `close` event on the dispatcher?

Could something like this work: (doesn't seem to in my case since `this` gets bound to window :)

```
Backbone.View.prototype.subscribeClose: (function(){
 dispatcher.on('close',this.close);
})();
```

This fails since `this` is bound to window. What would be a better way to pull this off or do I have to manually call a parent/prototype method to ensure that subscription always happens? Is there 'another' way in JS that I'm probably not aware of?

**UPDATE**: Adding a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/jF2Va/4/) Both the views should trigger on 'olay' but only one view in which the `subscribeOnClose` is added to the prototype seems to be working fine (experimented as per Dan's answer). Both views **do not** respond to the trigger though. Just simulating the trigger with a model for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I didn't want to bring this out unless really necessary, but if you really want this to apply to *all* view instances, without the need to have them descend from your own custom base view class, you can try something like this (overriding `Backbone.View`, the built-in base view class constructor):

http://jsfiddle.net/D9gR7/5/

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

  // Create your actual object here

  var dispatcher = _.clone( Backbone.Events );

  ( function () {

    var ctor = Backbone.View;

    Backbone.View = Backbone.View.extend( {

      constructor : function ( options ) {

        ctor.apply( this, arguments );

        dispatcher.on( 'close', this.close, this );

      },
      // constructor


      close : function () {

          console.log( this.cid );

      }
      // close

    } );

    Backbone.View.prototype.constructor = Backbone.View;

  } )();


  var View = Backbone.View.extend( {} );


  var views = [];

  var i;

  for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ) {

    views.push( new Backbone.View );

  }


  for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ) {

    views.push( new View );

  }

  dispatcher.trigger( 'close' );

} );
```

## Original Answer

There are a bunch of issues with your code. What about something like this (see the console for output, obviously)? I think this is pretty much what you're going for. You'd just need to make sure you call the parent `initialize()` when you override the method in sub classes. Also, if you want to completely blow away the view instances at some point, make sure you call `dispatcher.off( null, null, view_instance )`.

http://jsfiddle.net/D9gR7/

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

  // Create your actual object here

  var dispatcher = _.clone( Backbone.Events );

  var View = Backbone.View.extend( {

    initialize : function ( options ) {

      dispatcher.on( 'close', this.close, this );

    },


    close : function () {

      console.log( this.el.id );

    }

  } );


  var Some_Kind_Of_View = View.extend( {

    initialize : function ( options ) {

      View.prototype.initialize.apply( this, arguments );

      // ...

    }

  } );


  var view1 = new View( {

    el : $( "#MyDiv" )[0],

  } );


  var view2 = new Some_Kind_Of_View( {

    el : $( "#MyDiv2" )[0]

  } );


  dispatcher.trigger( 'close' );

} );
```

Some issues with your example code:

```
var V1 = Backbone.View.extend({

    // JMM: If you pass `el` to `extend()`, any instances you create
    // from the class will be tied to the same DOM element, unless
    // you pass a different `el` to the view constructors. Maybe
    // that's what you want.

    el: '#MyDiv',

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;

        // JMM: You're assigning `undefined` to this prototype
        // property. And you're trying to register the
        // return value of self.alert() (`undefined`) as
        // the handler for the `olay` event.

        Backbone.View.prototype.subOnClose = (function(){
            model.on('olay',self.alert('olay'));
        })();
    },

    alert: function(s) {
        alert('V1 -->' + s);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is the easy way :) Yes I know how to pull this off and that's not what I ask. I can always call the parent's method. I'm asking for something that happens "automagically" **without** having to call a parent method for every view in the app

Comment: Do you mean for every view *instance*, OR every view *class* that you create by calling `extend()`?

Comment: Every view instance must be subscribed to 'close' and thus would be defined somewhere in its class. Clearly stated in the question and updated w.r.t. your answer too :)

Comment: Well is it an option to create all of your view instances from a base class as suggested in my answer, or do they all have to be direct instances of `Backbone.View`? With the technique suggested in my answer you don't need to explicitly call anything when creating a view *instance*. As long as you instantiate them from the `View` class I defined, they'll be registered to listen for the event. Your question is not all that clear, and judging by your code I can't assume too much about your capabilities. I really don't think you should be so quick to downvote under the circumstances.

Comment: Well I do ask "is it possible to have all my views to be subscribed to close **without** having to call a parent class method or explicitly subscribing to it" - is there a 'trick' with self-executing functions that I could do to ensure that they are "always bound" without my needing to manually do it.

Comment: PS: The code is primarily a simplification for simulation and not intended for showcasing my capabilities :D

Comment: It's unclear to me when you're talking about view *instances* and when you're talking about view *classes* created by calling `extend()`. You said (paraphrasing) that you don't want to 'constantly call `dispatcher.on()` in every view that is an instance of Backbone.View'. With what I suggest you call `on()` in one place, and every view instantiated from that class will listen for the event. If you create view subclasses and override `initialize()`, all you have to do is call the parent `initialize()` *in the class*. Here's a simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D9gR7/1/

Comment: In the simplified fiddle, 10 view *instances* are created that all listen for the event, with no repetition of the `dispatcher.on()` code. Is that not what you're looking for? You could create those view instances however you want, as long as they're instances of the `View` class I defined (or whatever class you define the `initialize()` method in) -- I just created them in a loop for simplicity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15366/discussion-between-phd-and-jmm)