# Why does 'events' not get bound to the View when extending from a custom BaseView in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, events, inheritance, backbone.js

I'm trying to add a `BaseView` that performs some initialization for all Backbone views in my Module.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/fTrSj/2/) and the code is reproduced below

Creating a custom BaseView and having it subscribe to the 'close' event on the dispatcher. So as to have it be a part of all children on creation.

```
var dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events);

var ctor = Backbone.View;
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //override Backbone's constructor
    constructor: function(options) {

        ctor.apply(this, arguments);

        dispatcher.on('close', this.close, this);

    },

    close: function() {

        console.log(this.cid);

    }

});

//Is this really needed??
BaseView.prototype.constructor = Backbone.View;
```

Creating a child view inheriting from BaseView:

```
var View = BaseView.extend({
    el: '#clickholder',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },

    //Events not bound?
    events: {
        "click #clicker": "clicked"
    },

    //never called :(
    clicked: function(e) {
        alert("clicked button");
    }
});

new View();​
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<div id="clickholder">
<button id="clicker">Clicker</button>
</div>​
```

**Question:** If the button is clicked, the event is never fired and the alert is never shown. I'm not sure what the problem is. I've spent quite a while on it but can't fathom why is `events` not getting bound to the `View`? What am I doing wrong?

PS: This is based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11961470/609074). I specifically created a BaseView class so as to not have this globally effect all Backbone Views across my application but just keep it restricted to the specific module

**UPDATE**: fixed fiddle as per @mu's answer below. Wrapping the button in a div doesn't seem to solve the problem either. I erroneously had the view be bound to the button directly for simplification. In my main application the button is "within" the view's el so delegation worked just fine "before" the above BaseView was put into place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. Your Backbone code is running in the document `<head>` so there is no `#clicker` when it runs so there's nothing to bind the events to.
2. Your view's `el` is supposed to be `#clicker` but your event is trying to bind to `#clicker` *inside* `el`.  From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

   > **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
   >
   > [...] Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

   If you want to bind to a click on `el`, then you want:

   ```
   events: {
       "click": "clicked"
   }
   ```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fTrSj/

Comment: Sorry. My Bad. I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/fTrSj/2/ Having the button wrapped inside a div doesn't help either...

Comment: @PhD: You'd want `"click #clicker": "clicked"` in your events with that HTML, the selector part of the event has to be *inside* the view's `el`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fXhLd/

Comment: For some reason it never worked with my app :( I just scrapped it and rewrote it and it worked like a charm! I don't believe I was making such stupid blunders on the fiddle. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it!